# CMake header files can't be found (fatal error: file not found)

Tags: c++, cmake, header-files

I'm working on a CMake project but Im getting this error and I don't understand why. Im using VS Code on MacOS and I'm using Clang as the compiler.

Here is the structure of my folder project:

```
tree
.
├─ app
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── src
│       └── main.cpp
├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ build
└─ engine
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── external
    ├── include
    │   └── project_engine
    │       └── engine.h
    └── src
        └── engine.cpp
```

The root CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(vulkanEngine_developement_env VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_subdirectory(app)
add_subdirectory(engine)
```

The CMakeLists.txt in the app folder:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(vulkanEngine VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} vulkanEngine_engine)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE vulkanEngine_engine)
```

and the one in engine is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(vulkanEngine_engine VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/engine.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC 

    PRIVATE 
)
```

Whenever I try to include the header file in both cpp files I get the error "file not found", I tried using both

```
#include <project_engine/engine.h>
```

and

```
#include "project_engine/engine.h"
```

I also tried linking the path to the header in the vs code include path setting but it didn't work, I added include_directories to the engine CMake file but that didn't work either.

Comment: You must specify the include directory, using `targer_include_directories`. More info here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html

Comment: I read the documentation and tried changing the directory but it didn't work, unless I'm getting it wrong, I'm new to CMake. I edited the question with the new directory.

Comment: `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/project_engine>` should be changed to: `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>`! You've made this include path to long. So voting close as typo.

Comment: that was as I originally did it but still CMake couldn't find the header file